# Paragon software messed up MacOS High Sierra partitions

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, partition

I installed Windows 10 through Bootcamp and have been using it since 2015. Yesterday, I installed Paragon software which seemed to provide write access to NTFS partition.

But after installing that, I'm unable to find the Bootcamp partition. I tried booting from Windows partition via Paragon software, but I got error as "Unable to perform selected action". Therefore I removed the software manually, as uninstall also threw the same error. Even that did not solve the issue. In fact, now Startup Disk is not showing even the Macintosh partition. While booting, pressing Option key shows Macintosh partition, but not Bootcamp partition.

I tried manually mounting the partitions in /Volumes (which is empty now). That too did not solve the issue.

Is it possible to fix this without formatting the partition?

Comment: What OS, & more specifically what Paragon exactly? Older versions you had to switch off the NTFS write capability for Boot Camp to work. New versions don't suffer that limitation.

Comment: sorry, just noticed High Sierra in title :/

Comment: But I've removed Paragon, and still the partitions are not visible. In fact, Macintosh HD partition is not mounting, when I try from Disk Utility.